# Anaconda のインストール後に Anaconda Navigator が見つからない

Tags: windows, anaconda

anacondaをwindowsにインストールしたのですが、anaconda navigatorがないです。ネットの他のサイトを見ると、C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scriptsにexeファイルがあると書いてあったのですが見当たりません。また、anaconda promptでconda listと入力しても

```
'conda' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

と表示されます。アドバイスよろしくお願いします。

Comment: anaconda promptで、path と打ち込むとどんな表示がされるでしょうか? その中に anacondaのパスは入っているでしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

おそらく、インストール時に All Users ではなく、Just Me を選んだのだと思われます。
その場合は C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3 ではないでしょうか？
(ただしユーザー名に全角文字や空白が含まれると色々と不具合が発生しやすくなります)

この記事に近いのでは？ [Anaconda を Windows にインストールする手順](https://weblabo.oscasierra.net/python-anaconda-install-windows/)
　-> C:\Users\ユーザー名\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

<s>また、オプション選択時に「Add Anaconda to the system PATH environment variable」にチェックを入れていなかったのでしょう。その場合はコマンド名を入力しても、カレントディレクトリに該当コマンドが無ければ動作しません。</s>

その辺が良く分からないのならば、スタートメニューからたどっていって立ち上げるか、アンインストールして、オプションを見直して再インストールした方が良いと思われます。

ただし、こんな記事もありますので、何をどうするかは、注意した方が良いでしょう。
何かまとまった自己学習記事とか、プログラミングスクールのコースとかがあるのなら、その通りにしておくのも手だと思いますが。
[Windows(MS)にPython(Anaconda)を導入する（6つの罠）](https://qiita.com/kaizen_nagoya/items/7bfd7ecdc4e8edcbd679)
[AnacondaをWindowsにインストールする手順](https://b.ueda.tech/?page=anaconda_windows)
　-> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3　　(All Usersの場合)

[Anaconda で Python 環境をインストールする](https://qiita.com/t2y/items/2a3eb58103e85d8064b6)
　-> C:\Anaconda3

[Anacondaのインストール先について](https://teratail.com/questions/148313)
　-> C:\Users\ユーザー名\Anaconda3

---

ちょっとした版数違いでインストール先は色々変わっているのかもしれません。

[【Python】Anacondaのインストールと初期設定から便利な使い方までを徹底解説！](https://tkstock.site/2017/08/31/2017-08-31-195852/)
　-> C:\Anaconda3

[ここから始める！Anacondaで機械学習のためのPythonをインストール！(Windows編）](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/59340)
[【Python】非エンジニアWindowユーザー向けのAnacondaインストールの手順](https://tonari-it.com/python-anaconda-install/)
　-> C:\Users\ユーザー名\Anaconda3

---

コマンドが見つからない件は、以下のように色々と考えられますね。

- anaconda promptのつもりで通常のコマンドプロンプトを起動していた
- Anacondaをインストールした後、インストール先フォルダを移動した
- スタートメニューのリンクやバッチファイルのショートカット等の内容(パス)を書き換えた
- 管理者ユーザーのJust Meでインストールして、一般ユーザーで利用している
- ??env等で複数版数/環境を前提にしているが、上手く切り替わっていない
- conda と pip を混ぜて使った。[condaとpip：混ぜるな危険](http://onoz000.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/11/142347)

Comment: > オプション選択時に「Add Anaconda to the system PATH environment variable」にチェックを入れていなかった .... は、anaconda promptからの実行には関係ありません。　このオプションにチェックを入れると不具合が発生する事もあるとか、、と聞いた事もあります。

Comment: そうなのですか。ではその辺は違うわけですね。

Comment: もう一度インストールしたらちゃんとはいっていました。インストール時にコマンドプロンプトみたいな画面が表示されていたのですが、文字も何も書いてなかったので前回はバツ印で消していたのが原因だったように思います。

Comment: なるほど。サイズが大きくいろんなパッケージの寄せ集めなので、時間とステップがいっぱいかかり、どこまで進んだか何時終わるのかが見えにくいので不安になる、といったところでしょうか。