# ライブラリ”implicit”のインポート時のエラー解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

Tags: python, python3

pythonにてレコメンデーションを試してみたく、ライブラリ”implicit”をインストールしました。
しかし、インポートしようとすると以下エラーがでてしまいます。
このようなエラーの場合の解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

```
'''
import implicit

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-1eb90d3051a8> in <module>
----> 1 import implicit

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\implicit\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from . import als, approximate_als, bpr, lmf, nearest_neighbours
      2 
      3 __version__ = "0.6.2"
      4 
      5 __all__ = ["als", "approximate_als", "bpr", "nearest_neighbours", "lmf", "__version__"]

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\implicit\als.py in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 
----> 3 import implicit.cpu.als
      4 import implicit.gpu.als
      5 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\implicit\cpu\als.py in <module>
     12 from ..utils import check_blas_config, check_csr, check_random_state, nonzeros
     13 from . import _als
---> 14 from .matrix_factorization_base import MatrixFactorizationBase
     15 
     16 log = logging.getLogger("implicit")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\implicit\cpu\matrix_factorization_base.py in <module>
      6 
      7 from ..recommender_base import ModelFitError, RecommenderBase
----> 8 from .topk import topk
      9 
     10 

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing topk: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。
'''
```

回答に必要な情報が抜けているようでしたら、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。
OS：windows7
python version:3.8.5
conda version:4.9.2
インストールしたファイル:implicit-0.6.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Comment: ライブラリの要件にSciPyが必要と書かれていますが、インストールされているのでしょうか？

Comment: @TakahiroFunahashi  コメントありがとうございます。Scipy(version:1.5.2)もインストールしております。

Comment: Windows7は64ビット版ですか？

Comment: installしたときのコマンドは何でしょうか？

Comment: `conda`を記述しているということはAnaconda/Miniconda環境でしょうから、提示されているエラーメッセージのフォルダ構成と合わない感じです。`conda`と`pip`を混ぜて使っていませんか？ [Python プログラムを実行すると ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams' エラーが発生する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62095/26370), [pipをアップデートできない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53269/26370), [Anaconda のインストール後に Anaconda Navigator が見つからない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52774/26370) こうした場合、いったん全てアンインストール/再インストールするか、venv等で新規に分離した環境を作成・セットアップして試してみるのが良いと思われます。

Comment: @payaneco コメントありがとうございます。64ビット版です。

Comment: @merino コメントありがとうございます。次のコマンドでインストールいたしました。pip install ~\implicit-0.6.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl ----user

Comment: @kunif コメントありがとうございます。リンク先も拝見させていただきました。condaとpipを混ぜてはいけなかったのですね。勉強になりました！また新規に環境を作成してみたいと思います。